# Equivalent of static class/method of C# in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I want to create C++/CLI wrapper on the below C# code.

```
public static class Helper
{
  public static int? GetCodes(string input)
  {
    // Implementation of the logic.....
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: If the goal is to make an unmanaged C++ class that wraps that C# method, edit the question to say that. If you ask us for the equivalent to some C# code, the answers are going to be managed classes, not unmanaged.

Comment: “I want to create C++/CLI wrapper on the below C# code.” So, why don't you do that? Have you encountered some issues when doing it?

Comment: I am able to execute the code using abstract sealed. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

```
public ref class Helper abstract sealed
{
public:
    static System::Nullable<int> GetCodes(System::String^ input) { /* impl logic */ }
};
```